# Spring Cloud Launcher Custom Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to launch my app from the spring cloud launcher config.yml under deployables in the yml. I want to deploy my apps dependencies live in dev.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    launcher:
      deployables:
        application:
          coordinates: maven://com.app.appy:application:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I'm trying to follow [this section](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-cli/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__running_spring_cloud_services_in_development.html#_adding_additional_applications) in the docs on custom applications being defined in ./config/cloud.yml but my spring boot app doesn't work.

I want to execute this command:

```
spring cloud eureka configserver application
```